# No puedo inyectar BCryptEncoder en linux pero si en windows

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, intellij-idea

mi proyecto spring mvc/security no puede inicializar porque hay un problema con el BCryptEncoder:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder]
```

El mismo código y entorno (Intellij 2016, java 1.8, mySQL 5.7, tomcat 8, maven 3.3) funciona bien en windows.

BCryptPasswordEncoder es llamado en my userService:

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

BCryptPasswordEncoder se define en mi SecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
```

Y en el pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Si navego desde Intellij a la definiciónd de la clase, la encuentro en mi carpeta de librerías.

No tengo más pistas. Es muy extraño que funcione solo en Windows y no en linux. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Se publicó en el sitio en castellano, pensé que estaba en el inglés. Porfa, votalo positivo.

Comment: Ya la has traducido, y he retirado mi voto de cierre. Yo no he votado ni a favor ni en contra ya que no conozco del tema que planteas y no se cual es la calidad de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Cambié el atributo en la clase, de

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

por:

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
```